# Как посчитать процент элемента от экрана android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Дана картинка 326x189 px На androd я ее принимаю как 326dpx189dp Вот допустим есть экран android 1440x2960 560dpi Я хочу вычислить сколько картинка будет %x% в ширину и высоту. Я нашел формулу
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
Вычисляю:

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
шк = шкdp / dp
вк = вкdp / dp
dpш = 1440 / (560 / 160) = 411
шк = 326 / 411 = 0.79
dpв = 2960 / (560 / 160) = 845.7
вк = 189 / 845.7 = 0.22
```

Получается как вы понимаете полный бред особенно с высотой. Как подсчитать?

Comment: [`DisplayMetrics.xdpi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#xdpi) и такой же `ydpi`. [Получение размера картинки в пикселях](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128526). Теперь, разделив количество пикселей в картинке в любом измерении на соответствующую плотность, найдём ширину и высоту изображения в дюймах

Comment: Может проще все считать в dp? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065972/5479247

Comment: И ваши расчеты относительно корректны: 79% по ширине, 22% по высоте. Что тут не так по вашему?

Comment: Так то оно так но когда я ставлю эти размеры процентов в ConstraintLayout то там только похоже на правду ширина а высота нет.